# Sample Java EE projects using Java EE design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, 3-tier

For .Net there are lots of projects that Microsoft/others provide via which one can learn how patterns etc. are implemented in real life projects.

I am looking for ones for Java EE (apart from the samples that Sun provides on:http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/). Am looking for more complex ones. May be using JSF/Spring/Struts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sun provides [BluePrints](http://java.sun.com/reference/blueprints/) (with the famous Pet Store and the Adventure Builder applications) that show [patterns](http://bpcatalog.dev.java.net/) and how they can be implemented using Java EE APIs. About the [Java PetStore 2.0](https://blueprints.dev.java.net/petstore/):

> The Java Pet Store 2.0 is the reference application for building AJAX web applications on Java EE 5. It illustrates BluePrints for using AJAX with Java, building AJAX-enabled JSF component libraries, using Java Persistence APIs, applying MVC and other design patterns in an AJAX web app, using Mashups such as Google Maps service for location specific searches of pets and PayPal service for purchases, using an RSS feed as a data  source, and lots more.

Note that for versions prior to Java EE 5, I really don't think one should consider them as representative of best/good practices but only as technology showcases. Java EE 5 has made things much better.

Still, you should have a look at Spring's PetStore sample application (which  illustrates iBATIS integration if I remember well) too. It's definitely worth the check.

And you may found others samples like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/spring-petstore/) (and many others, just google for "Java PetStore").

Comment: Now Sun belongs to Oracle,and they have taken care of 9 year past links

Answer (score 3):

There are several. One possibility is the [AppFuse](http://www.appfuse.org) project. It gives you some options to choose frameworks and see a full app generated. You can [start here](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart).

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Pet Store](https://blueprints.dev.java.net/petstore/) demo is a reference application using JSF.  It's referenced on the page at the bottom, but it's hidden away at the bottom.  This, and the [Java BluePrints](http://java.sun.com/reference/blueprints/) project, are a good reference about patterns in a decent sized project.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a series of articles, addressing Java EE application design and implementation, using a concrete example. For the implementation, it will use Spring, Hibernate and MySql. But, the ideas are quite general that can be applied with any technology.
[enter link description here](http://nazar-merza.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample project of a 3-tier Java EE 7 web application `(an application that allows users to view movie listings and make reservations)` from Javaone 2013 [here](http://glassfish.org/hol/javaee7-hol.pdf). It has a link where you can download the sample and improve on it as the tutorial progresses. It uses `JSF` for its user interface, `javascript` and `JSON` to communicate with a `Websocket endpoint`, `RESTful` web services etc.